# Problem with compile files to dynamic library

Tags: c

I am trying compile to dynamic libary,
main.c:

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math_utils.h>
int main(){
    int x,y;
    scanf("%i%i", &x, &y);
    printf("%i\n%i", gcd(x, y), lcm(x, y));
}`
```

math_utils.h

```
#pragma once

int gcd(int x, int y);

int lcm(int x, int y);
```

math_utils.c

```
#include "math_utils.h"

int gcd(int x, int y){
    int i;
    for(i = smaller(x,y); i>0; --i){
        if(x%i==0 && y%i==0){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int lcm(int x, int y){
    int big = bigger(x, y);
    int small = smaller(x, y);
    int iteration = 1;
    while((big*iteration)%small!=0){
        ++iteration;
    }
    return big*iteration;
}

int smaller(int x, int y){
    if(x<y){
        return x;
    }
    return y;
}

int bigger(int x, int y){
    if(x>y){
        return x;
    }
    return y;
}
```

commands in the console:

1. gcc -fPIC -c math_utils.c
2. gcc -shared -o libmath.dll math_utils.o
3. gcc -o app main.c libmath.dll

After last i got it error:
main.c:3:10: fatal error: math_utils.h: No such file or directory
#include <math_utils.h>

Can anyone explain me ,why my main dont see math..
Thanks for every answer.

All files are in one folder

I am expecting to have dynamic library

Comment: Use `"math_utils.h"`, not `<math_utils.h>`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: And when I use "math_utils.h" i will still use a library and not just a file with extention .c?

Comment: When you use `math_utils.h` you will use the file `math_utils.h`. That is totally unrelated to shared library.

Comment: Soo how use function which i added, from library?